# How do I enable automatic capitalization in OS X?

Tags: macos

Can I turn on automatic capitalization on my iMac running OS X 10.9, Mavericks? It is selectable in iOS on my iPad but I can't find a similar switch in Mavericks.

Comment: Are you perchance meaning the menu item under Edit > Transformations > Capitalize ? Or you looking for a different solution? If different how?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a third party such as [TextExpander](http://smilesoftware.com/TextExpander/index.html) ($35) for this. Paired with the right third party dictionary (TidBITS Autocorrect Dictionary), which is downloadable from within TextExpander, it corrects most of my typos that Mac OS X misses, as well as providing shortcuts for frequently typed snippets.

Using TextExpander just for sentence capitalization is a bit of overkill, but if you embrace it, you wind up with an excellent tool that you can easily adapt to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

It's not available yet on Mavericks as such.  You can ask Apple to add it via

http://www.apple.com/feedback

Some apps might have it internally (but Pages 5 does not, only Pages 4).